# Multiplicar por el mayor en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la sienguiente consulta

```
SELECT   
   f.SE_Factura, 
   SE_Consecutivo_Embarque,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Compra,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Venta,
   f.SE_Fecha_OV,   
   f.SE_Cliente_Despachar_A,
   (f.SE_Peso*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Peso, 
   (f.SE_Volumen*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Volumen    
FROM SE_FactEmbarque f  
INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e  
ON  e.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta   
AND (e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = 
f.SE_Codigo_Articulo) 
where f.SE_Factura = 'CD-40348'
```

la cual me trae los siguientes datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que estoy tratando de hacer y debo hacer es saber cual de los dos es mayor si el peso o el volumen y multiplicarlo por la tarifa de la siguiente tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el SE_Cliente_Despachar_A es igual al SE_Cliente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de la sentencia `CASE` es muy útil en estos casos, agrego la nueva columna a tu consulta, espero te sirva.

```
SELECT   
   f.SE_Factura, 
   SE_Consecutivo_Embarque,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Compra,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Venta,
   f.SE_Fecha_OV,   
   f.SE_Cliente_Despachar_A,
   (f.SE_Peso*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Peso, 
   (f.SE_Volumen*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Volumen,
   (CASE WHEN f.SE_Peso > f.SE_Volumen THEN f.SE_Peso ELSE f.SE_Volumen) * e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada
FROM SE_FactEmbarque f  
INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e  
    ON  e.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta   
    AND (e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = 
    f.SE_Codigo_Articulo) 
where f.SE_Factura = 'CD-40348'
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `CASE WHEN` puedes dar solución a tu problema, es decir, primero validar si el `Peso` es mayor al `Volumen` y realizar la operación:

```
SELECT   
   f.SE_Factura, 
   SE_Consecutivo_Embarque,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Compra,
   f.SE_Orden_De_Venta,
   f.SE_Fecha_OV,   
   f.SE_Cliente_Despachar_A,
   (f.SE_Peso*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Peso, 
   (f.SE_Volumen*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Volumen,
   CASE 
        WHEN Peso > Volumen THEN (Peso * SE_Tarifa)
        ELSE (Volumen * SE_Tarifa)
    END 
FROM SE_FactEmbarque f  
INNER JOIN SE_Embarques e  
ON  e.SE_Orden_De_Venta = f.SE_Orden_De_Venta   
AND (e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = f.SE_EAN_Articulo OR e.SE_Codigo_Articulo = 
f.SE_Codigo_Articulo) 
where f.SE_Factura = 'CD-40348'
```

Comment: Me sale un error al poner WHEN Peso > Volumen THEN (Peso * SE_Tarifa)
        ELSE (Volumen * SE_Tarifa) en Peso y volumen, por que vienen del AS Peso y AS Volumen

Comment: @Eduard ¿Cuál es el error que te sale?

Comment: Nombre de la columa Peso no valido, Nombre de la columna Volumen no valido

Comment: El valor que me da (f.SE_Peso*e.SE_Cantidad_Embarcada)*400 as Peso lo guardo con el alias peso y ese valor es el que va en el CASE, lo mismo para el volumen